# When is the preimage of prime ideal is not a prime ideal?

Tags: ring-theory

If $f\colon R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism such that $f(1)=1$, it's straightforward to show that the preimage of a prime ideal is again a prime ideal.

What happens though if $f(1)\neq 1$? I use the fact that $f(1)=1$ to show that the preimage of a prime ideal is proper, so I assume there is some example where the preimage of a prime ideal is not proper, and thus not prime when $f(1)\neq 1$? Could someone enlighten me on such an example?

Comment: Dear sachiko, You may be interested in this question and the accompanying answers: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34332/consequences-of-not-requiring-ring-homomorphisms-to-be-unital  Regards,

Answer (score 6):

Consider the "rng" homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ where $f(n)=0$; then $(0)$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Q}$, but $f^{-1}(0)=\mathbb{Z}$ is not proper, hence not prime.

A different example would be $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ where $f(1)=(1,0)$; then for any prime ideal $P\subset \mathbb{Z}$, we have that $I=\mathbb{Z}\oplus P$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$, but $f^{-1}(I)=\mathbb{Z}$ is not proper, hence not prime.

Comment: is this what counts as studying these days?

Comment: @jspecter: Nope, this counts firmly as procrastination... :)

Comment: @ZevChonoles I don't think your second example is valid since it is not a ring homomorphism: $f(1\cdot1)=2\neq 2\cdot 2 =f(1)f(1)$.

Comment: @A.B Take another look at the context of the question - the OP is using a definition of ring homomorphisms that does not require this. See also my comment below jspecter's answer.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Don't we always have $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ for a ring homomorphism? I'm not familiar of a definition that allows for the absence of this condition. If the issue is with the $1$, then doesn't the fact that $f(2\cdot2)=8 \neq 16 =f(2)f(2)$ also show this isn't valid?

Comment: Ah, indeed you're right - my mistake. 1 must always be taken to an idempotent.

Answer (score 4):

First, I object to the fact that you consider maps which don't take $1_R$ to $1_S$ to be ring homomorphisms.

That said, yes if you were to consider such maps there are many examples. For example let $R$ be any integral domain, $S = R\oplus R$ and $f:R \rightarrow S$ be the embedding of $R$ into the first coordinate in $S$. Then $f(R)$ is a prime ideal of $S.$ And voila a counterexample.

Comment: I find the idea to be objectionable too, but (depending on one's definitions) a ring need not contain a multiplicative identity, in which case it is only fair to make a distinction between "a ring homomorphism between two rings that happen to have unity" and "a ring-with-unity homomorphism".